# What does 我在包里 mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does this phrase mean? 我在包里。 In English this is slang for being drunk, but I wonder what it means in Chinese. I was told this last night, by my girlfriend last night and I am wondering if it carries the same meaning.

Comment: do you have any context?

Answer (score 2):

> 我在包里

is a literal translation of

> I'm in the bag

which means "I'm drunk" in English. While the Chinese sentence does not have any relationship with 'drunk' at all.

Here are some phrases that mean I'm drunk in chinese:

我喝醉了

我喝多了

我断片了 (I'm so drunk that lost my memory)

Answer (score 0):

If it means "being drunk"

then I think it is just a mimicking of drunken talk or child words:

在 /zài/ is sound-alike of 醉 /zuì/

包 /bāo/ is sound-alike of 饱 /bǎo/ or 爆/bào/

里 /lǐ/ is sound-alike of 呢 /ne/

在包里 is a drunken talk of 醉饱呢 or 醉爆呢

Similar example:

喜歡 /Xǐhuān/ --> 稀飯 /Xīfàn/

什麼 /Shénme/ --> 神馬 /Shénmǎ/